# HTML img - passing file name as parameter

Tags: html, image, url, parameters

I would like a HTML to get an image file name as a parameter from another page and display that image. I only know a bit of HTML. I don't know PHP etc.

I have a website which has several HTML pages. I want to write an  "image container" page which will be called from other pages. The other pages will pass it a bitmap file name and the container page will display that image.
Ideally the container page should be getting few other parameter like the width and height of the image.

In showimage.html:

Instead of this:

```
<img src="bitmaps/test.jpg" height="200">
```

Have something like this:

```
<img src="{parameter 1}" height="{parameter 2}">
```

And the calling page will call showimage.html with "bitmaps/test.jpg" and "200".

Comment: HTML can't do this. You need a programming language.

Comment: OK :-( thank you. I will look for a JavaScript solution.